# Servlet under tomcat error

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to create a simple servlet exemple I am using java 1.7 and tomcat server 7. When I deploy my project I get a HTTP 404 error. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class IMCServlet
 */

public class IMCServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public IMCServlet() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
    out.println("<HTML>");
    out.println("<HEAD><TITLE> Calculer votre IMC</TITLE></HEAD>");
    out.println("<BODY>");
    out.println("<Text goes here...>");
    out.println("</BODY>");
    out.println("</HTML>");
    out.close();

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

here is the web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN"            "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">
<web-app id="WebApp_ID">
<display-name>IMCServlet</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>IMCServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>IMCServlet</display-name>
    <description>Servlet qui stock le IMC dans une base de données</description>
    <servlet-class>ca.uqac.Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IMCServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/IMCServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>Index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Can anyone please help, thanks.
After all I figure it out I had to change this

```
<servlet-class>ca.uqac.Servlet</servlet-class>
```

to

```
<servlet-class>ca.uqac.Servlet.IMCServlet</servlet-class>
```

Comment: You don't get 404 when you deploy. You get a 404 when you try to send a request to a URI that isn't handled. What URI did you try?

Comment: thank you for your answer the URI is http://localhost:8080/IMC/servlet/ca.uqac.Servlet.IMCServlet

Comment: Now do you see any handlers for that path in your deployment descriptor (the web.xml)?

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner, I don't really understand what are the handlers?

Comment: I don't want to straight up give you the answer. Think about it for a second. What is a `Servlet`? Why do you have a `<servlet-mapping>`? What is the `<url-pattern>`?

Comment: I like the way you answer it will help me to understand. As far as I know a servlet is a simple java class with the exception that it communicates with a remote server. a <servlet-mapping> is to locate your servlet in the server, <url-pattern> is like the way the servlet communicates with the server, it is the path to the servlet in the server, I am thinking of a port conflict maybe. Right?

Comment: can you check for existence of welcome file.?

Comment: I checked it does not exists

Comment: Why are you giving "localhost:8080/IMC/servlet/ca.uqac.Servlet.IMCServlet". I think you need to give path "localhost:8080/IMC/IMCServlet", you need to pass URl to the servlet, and i think you are passing location of class to the container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is exactly what I have done and it worked, I was parsing the location of the container.

Comment: You should put your servlet into a "package". I think the spec even officially requires it, though there don't seem to be any technical restrictions that should prohibit you from using a package-less class as a servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 < servlet-class >
      ca.uqac.Servlet
 < /servlet-class >
```

to

```
 < servlet-class >
      ca.uqac.IMCServlet
  < /servlet-class >
```

Hope the `IMCServlet` class is in ca.uqac package